# How to Sort Custom columns in admin

Tags: posts

I have set a custom column for date in admin, but the sorting is not working, when I click to sort the dates are jumbled up and not sorted correctly. This is the sorting function Im using

```
function sortable_columns() {
    return array(
        // meta column id => sortby value used in query
        'publishdate' => 'date', // e.g. 1344964575            
    );
} add_filter( "manage_edit-post_sortable_columns", "sortable_columns" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial from WPTuts+ will do the trick ... [Quick Tip: Make Your Custom Column Sortable](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-make-your-custom-column-sortable/)

> In a [recent article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen/) by Claudio Simeone, he demonstrated how you could add extra columns to your post, or custom post type, admin screens (or remove existing ones). In this quick tip I build on that by showing you how to make your newly created columns sortable.