# How should i sort “Last Update” Custom Column?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type name “Organization” in which there is a field called “Last Update”. I save data of this field using

```
update_post_meta( $company_id, 'profile_updated_on', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
```

In Database data stored as

```
   meta_key           meta_value
1) profile_updated_on 1516763741
2) profile_updated_on 1516691767
3) profile_updated_on 1516691769
```

Now in custom post type admin dashboard i’m not able to sort this “Last Updated” field. I used this below code for sorting which is not sorting correctly.

```
// Add the custom columns to the organization post type:
add_filter( 'manage_edit-organization_columns', 'set_custom_edit_organization_columns' );
function set_custom_edit_organization_columns($columns) {

    $columns['profile_updated_on'] = __( 'Last Updated', 'cthe' );
    return $columns;
}

// Add the data to the custom columns for the organization post type:
add_action( 'manage_organization_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_organization_column', 10, 2 );
function custom_organization_column( $column_name, $post_id ) {

    if('profile_updated_on' != $column_name)
        return;

    $profile_updated_on_timestamp = get_post_meta( $post_id , 'profile_updated_on' , true );

    //echo date_i18n($profile_updated_on);
    echo get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d ', $profile_updated_on_timestamp ), 'F j, Y' );
}

function your_columns_head($defaults) {  

    $new = array();
    $updated_by = $defaults['profile_updated_on'];  // save the tags column


    foreach($defaults as $key=>$value) {
        if($key=='date') {  // when we find the date column
           $new['profile_updated_on'] = $updated_by;  // put the tags column before it
        }    
        $new[$key]=$value;
    }  
    return $new; 

} 
add_filter('manage_organization_posts_columns', 'your_columns_head');


function set_custom_organization_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['profile_updated_on'] = 'profile_updated_on';

    //To make a column 'un-sortable' remove it from the array
    //unset($columns['title']);

  return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-organization_sortable_columns', 'set_custom_organization_sortable_columns' );
```

Using this i'm getting result like:

```
1) January 23, 2018 22:15
2) January 23, 2018 22:49
3) January 23, 2018 02:16
```

I had also follow [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62957/how-to-sort-custom-columns-in-admin/62961); but i'm not able to get exact result.

Using `pre_get_posts` hook

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_organization_orderby' );

function my_organization_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'Last Updated' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','profile_updated_on');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    }
}
```

I have tried `meta_value_num` with `date`

Comment: Have you _read_ that article? They're hooking into `pre_get_posts` there.

Comment: Using `pre_get_posts` i am not able to make the column sort able.

Comment: Add the code you've used with `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Please review my edited answer. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderby` will not contain the title of the column that is being clicked on, but its ID. Change your `pre_get_posts` filter to

```
function my_organization_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'profile_updated_on' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','profile_updated_on');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    }
}
```